# Merging parts of JSON objects in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Is there an easy way in javascript (running on nodejs) to merge various attributes of an object in an array? I know I can do it using some for loops etc, but was wondering if there is any easier way. My array of objects is like this -

```
 [
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
      "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": {
      "category_name": "Tom",
      "category_rank": 78,
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    }
  },
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
      "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": {
      "category_name": "Dick",
      "category_rank": 103,
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    }
  },
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
      "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": {
      "category_name": "Harry",
      "category_rank": 267,
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    }
  },
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
      "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": {
      "category_name": "Tom",
      "category_rank": 42,
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    }
  },
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
       "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": {
      "category_name": "Dick",
      "category_rank": 60,
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    }
  },
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
       "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": {
      "category_name": "Harry",
      "category_rank": 132,
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    }
  }
]
```

And I would like them to be merged like this based on date_of_extraction

```
[
  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
      "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank":[
      {
        "category_name": "Tom",
        "category_rank": 78,
        "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Dick",
        "category_rank": 103,
        "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Harry",
        "category_rank": 267,
        "date_of_extraction": "2020-07-04"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "asin": "123456",
    "isbn": "09876543",
    "title": "Joe bloggs",
    "country": "us",
    "published_date": "2019-07-30",
    "AmazonProductPageInfo": {
      "id": 1108,
      "title_asin": "123456",
      "country": "us",
      "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
    },
    "AmazonCategoryRank": [
      {
        "category_name": "Tom",
        "category_rank": 42,
        "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Dick",
        "category_rank": 60,
        "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Harry",
        "category_rank": 132,
        "date_of_extraction": "2020-04-20"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why downvote? Its a legit question with proper explanation and all... care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good npm package called [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge) looking at it might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Hadi, but this is not exatcly what I need. I tried it and it seems to be merging everythinhg and missing out a lot of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code via loops or just with functions such as [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in code of course.

If you're looking for a totally *different* way, databases are also quite good at grouping data. I'm doing something similar using [mongodb-memory-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-memory-server) where I am making a temporary collection then streaming a large set of raw data into it and then using mongo aggregate pipelines to do the transformation work.

In this case for you, assuming you stream your sample records into a collection, your query may look something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$AmazonProductPageInfo.date_of_extraction",
      asin: { $first: "$asin" },
      isbn: { $first: "$isbn" },
      title: { $first: "$title" }, 
      country: { $first: "$country" },
      published_date: { $first: "$published_date" },
      AmazonProductPageInfo: { $first: "$AmazonProductPageInfo" },
      AmazonCategoryRank: { $push: "$AmazonCategoryRank" }, // $push here
    }
  }
])
```

Where you use `$first` to pick the first scalar value for each field of the group, assuming they are all the same and use `$push` for the category rank objects which are distinct per group. That should give you your desired results.

You can then use a cursor to iterate over them all or do further transformations or aggregations in the same pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I will try your approach. Basically, I am getting this data from a DB using Sequelize ORM, but I guess I am not doing the grouping correctly. Let me try this and see where I get to.